# How to check the version of an application installed with Homebrew (Mac)?

Tags: macos, mac, homebrew, gcc

I'd like to check the version of GCC on my macOS, found this command:

```
$ gcc -dumpversion | cut -f1 -f2 -f3 -d
```

If I want to check my brew-installed GCC --version (or any other app) what would be the command?

Thank you!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To see which version(s) of a particular *utility* you have installed using `brew`, e.g. `gcc`, use:

```
brew list --versions gcc
```

Comment: works only last argument - `gcc`

Comment: Just logging that `--casks` is needed for casks - duh

Example `brew list --versions --casks netbeans`